# How can solve requesting "dart.ui" in Flutter while Integration Testing

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am doing integration testing to my Login Page. Here the error that I got. How can I solve this error.

> C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_project>flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart Found multiple connected devices: SM J210F                  • 4200a590689b1400 • android-arm • Android
>   6.0.1 (API 23) Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554    • android-x86 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator) Using device SM J210F.
>   Starting application: test_driver/app.dart Installing
>   build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...                        92.6s Running
>   Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... I/flutter ( 5922): Observatory
>   listening on http://127.0.0.1:54862/GeAeXgP3k4M=/
>
> E/FlutterFcmService( 5922): Fatal: failed to find callback
>
> I/flutter ( 7271): Observatory listening on
>   http://127.0.0.1:48093/UgDcJGtlUI0=/
>
> E/FlutterFcmService( 7271): Fatal: failed to find callback
>
> registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>
> registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>
> registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) Running Gradle task
>   'assembleDebug'...                             95.3s √ Built
>   build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk. Installing
>   build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...                        28.1s Package
>   install error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
>   Uninstalling old version... Installing
>   build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...                        93.1s
>   I/flutter ( 8617): Observatory listening on
>   http://127.0.0.1:54916/WUrIswnOm3g=/ E/FlutterFcmService( 8617):
>   Fatal: failed to find callback /
>
> - D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.13.4+2/lib/cloud_firestore.dart:8:8:
>     Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' show hashList;
> - ^    /D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.12/lib/firebase_messaging.dart:7:8:
>     Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui';
> - ^    /D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:9:8:
>     Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' as ui show Paint, Path,
>     Canvas;
> - /D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:10:8:
>     Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> - ^ /D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:5:8: Error:    Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' as ui;
> - ^    /D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: 
>     Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> - ^ /D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:6:8: Error:    Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> - ^    /D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_app_bar_theme.dart:5:8:
>     Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> - ^    /D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet_theme.dart:5:8:
>     Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> - ^    /D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/button_bar_theme.dart:5:8:
>     Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
>              ^
> - Stopping application instance. Driver tests failed: 254

My app_test.dart code

```
import 'package:flutter_driver/flutter_driver.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';`


void main() {
group("Flutter Auth Test", () {
  final emailField = find.byValueKey("emailfield");
  final passwordField = find.byValueKey("passwordfield");
  final signbutton = find.byValueKey("log");
  final adminPage = find.byValueKey("home");
  final userPage = find.byValueKey("userp");

  FlutterDriver driver;
  setUpAll(()async{
    driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
  });

  tearDownAll(()async{
    if(driver != null) {
      driver.close();
    }
  });

  test("login with incorrect email and password",() async{
    await driver.tap(emailField);
    await driver.enterText("test@gmail.com");
    await driver.tap(passwordField);
    await driver.enterText("test123");
    await driver.tap(signbutton);
    await driver.waitUntilNoTransientCallbacks();
    assert(adminPage == null && userPage == null);
  });

  test("login admin with correct email and password",() async {
    await driver.tap(emailField);
    await driver.enterText("madhuwanthiaah@gmail.com");
    await driver.tap(passwordField);
    await driver.enterText("admin123");
    await driver.tap(signbutton);
    assert(adminPage != null && userPage == null);

  });

  test("login user with correct email and password",() async {
    await driver.tap(emailField);
    await driver.enterText("cst16029@gmail.com");
    await driver.tap(passwordField);
    await driver.enterText("user123");
    await driver.tap(signbutton);
    assert(userPage != null && adminPage == null);
  });
});
}
```

Comment: Can you share the tests you are trying to execute alongwith the imports you are using in it ? You can't use `dart.ui` import in your integration tests.

Comment: I will edit my question.Thank for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question updating my packages and run,
 `flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart` command.
It works for me. I used android emulator for this testing.